# C++ program crashes when counter is used inside loop

Tags: c++, math, for-loop, divide-by-zero, dividebyzeroexception

I am working on a very small program to find the divisors of an integer in C++.
My main method pretty much cins an int to a var and calls the factor method with the int as the argument.
Here's the code:

```
void factor(int num)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < ((num + 2) / 2); x++)
    {
        if((num % x) == 0)
        {
            cout << x << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

The program always crashes inside factor().
If I use this code, it runs fine:

```
void factor(int num)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < ((num + 2) / 2); x++)
    {
        {
            cout << x << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is somewhere in the `if((num % x) == 0)`. When I change that line to `if((num % 2) == 0)` or `if((num % 5) == 0)`, it produces the right results (I'm using 32 as the test input).

I learned C++ a few years ago and forgot most of it, after running into this issue I copied the code word for word off of my previous solution to this problem (which worked). But the program still crashes whenever I try to access the loop counter.

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 with GCC "4.9.0 20140604 (prerelease)" on Arch Linux 64-bit.

Comment: Of course `(num % x)` will _'crash'_, when `x` is `0`!

Comment: Simple knowledge of basic math, you can't divide by 0, neither can your program...

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with C++, except he has used `cout`, it is more of maths error :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you have an [*division-by-zero*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero) in your first snippet, something which is *undefined-behavior* according to the standard (n3337):

> `5.6p4` **Multiplicative operators** `[expr.mul]`
>
> > The binary `/` operator yields the quotient, and the binary `%` operator yeilds the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of `/` or `%` is zero the behavior is undefined.

---

Since the program cannot calculate the value of such expression it will crash.

```
if((num % x) == 0)  // num % 0 on first iteration, application will crash, or order pizza
{
  cout << x << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How can you do `num%x` when x is 0? Due to use of x when it is 0, program crashes.

This would cause a runtime error which I suppose would be `SIGFPE`.

Comment: I guess reading (and posting) the error message would sometimes help...

Comment: When I ran it from CodeBlocks, the only message it gave was "Process returned -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)   execution time : 1.479 s     Press ENTER to continue." I'm really new to CodeBlocks, I previously used Eclipse CDT, so I couldn't get any more details about what went wrong.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CodeBlocks as I already commented. It is a maths error. So please re-think your logic for code so that there would be no reason to do division by zero. Or, tell what do you want do so that there might be some suggestions from answerers.

Answer (score 0):

In the very first cycle of the for x has the value 0. num % x would require a division by 0 which is a mathematical non-sense and that is where is crashes.

You want to see all the divisors of the number (they divide the number and 0 is left to carry over). You should start the for cycle at 2. (1 is already a given - you could print him out directly, but you going to only half the number, so I suspect you are not interested in 1 and the number itself).

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the loop from `x = 1`.

Starting from 0 does not make any sense, if you want to compute the factors of a number.
The `%` operator computes the remainder of the divison `num/x`. A division by 0 does not make any sense, so the behavior of the operation is undefined. This means it can crash with one compiler/machine and can produce some sort of result on another compiler/machine.